# Kotlin Jetpack Compose Webview Element Slip

Tags: kotlin, webview, android-jetpack-compose

I am showing the html codes in the webview, but there is a problem with the location of the elements.
Here how it should look like ;
[image: should look like]

But it looks like this ;

[image: looks like this]

I'm talking about the webview not bar dont take,ignore the bar

Here my detail page codes;

```
@Composable
fun ShowHtmlContentFromJson(htmlContent: String) {
val context = LocalContext.current

val webView = remember {
    WebView(context).apply {
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true // JavaScript'i etkinleştirmek için
        webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
    }
}

AndroidView(
    factory = { webView },
    update = {
        it.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
    },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
)
}
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter", 
"CoroutineCreationDuringComposition")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Detaysayfa(scp: MenuItem)
{
var expandVal = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var osman by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

val context = LocalContext.current

val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel(
    factory = AnasayfaViewModelFactory(context.applicationContext as Application)
)

CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    osman = viewModel.retrofitTekGetirAnasayfa(scp).content
}

Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
)
{
    Scaffold(
        content = {
                  Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                  verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                  modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(top = 65.dp))
                  {
                      ShowHtmlContentFromJson(htmlContent = osman)
                  }
        },
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Column()
                    {
                        Text("Scp Okuyucu")
                        Text(
                            scp.title,
                            fontSize = 12.sp,
                        )
                    }
                },
                actions = {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.menu_white),
                        "",
                        tint = Color.White,
                        modifier = Modifier.clickable { expandVal.value = true })

                    DropdownMenu(
                        expanded = expandVal.value,
                        onDismissRequest = { expandVal.value = false })
                    {
                        DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Ana Sayfa") }, onClick = { })
                        DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Favoriler") }, onClick = { })
                    }
                },
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.largeTopAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = Color.Black,
                    titleContentColor = Color.White
                )
            )
        }
     )
   }
 }
```

TLDR : There is a shifting problem in the elements I show in the webview I use Jetpack Composed, how can I solve this?